# Count Female And Male Student using function in pl/sql

Tags: plsql

I would like to create a function in PL/SQL that returns the number of males and females in the database. I created a function which returns the number of either males or females in the database, but not both. This is the code I used.

This is the the code I used to create the function:

```
create or replace function totalstudent
return number is
total_male number(2):=0;
begin
select count(*) into total_male from New_Student where gender='Male';
return total_male;
end;
```

The code I used to call it:

```
declare 
c number(2);
begin
c:=totalstudent();
dbms_output.put_line('Total Number of Male is'||c);
end;
/
```

Here is the
[result produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twMmV.jpg)

Briefly, I want a function which will do what that function does but also display the number of Female entries... Both Female and Male entries are in the Database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your requirements are. I suggest using an input parameter:

-- These are the codes I used to create the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalstudent (v_gender IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
IS
    total_gender   NUMBER (2) := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT (*)
      INTO total_gender
      FROM New_Student
     WHERE gender = v_gender;

    RETURN total_gender;
END;

-- The code I used to call it

DECLARE
    c   NUMBER (2);
BEGIN
    c := totalstudent ('Male');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Total Number of Male is' || c);
    c := totalstudent ('Female');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Total Number of Female is' || c);
END;
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Fabricio, I was complicating things by returning multiple values. And this just solved my Problem :-)

Comment: Do not forget to rate the answers, greetings!

Comment: @LenzVital You declared a `number(2)` this means you'll get an exception if you have more than 99 males or females in your db. And like Fabricio said: Don't forget to accept the answer as corred ;)

Comment: Thanks for yout commet. I think that this depende of the requirements of the user or database. For example, function would have an exception for count > 99 or another value.